# How can I create a button for clickable many times on android?

Tags: java, android

I triying make a android app for learning but my buttons clickable only once. I can't click second time. Here is my codes for button.

There is the xml codes:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:width="200dp"
    android:height="80dp"
    android:shadowColor="@color/red"
    android:text="@string/button"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:cornerRadius="100dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text"
    app:rippleColor="@color/red"
    app:strokeColor="@color/red"
    tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />
```

And there is java codes:

```
buttonGenerate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        passwordText.setText(generate());
    }
});
```

There is generate method:

```
private String generate () {
Random random = new Random();
int character;
while (password.length() < 16) {
character = random.nextInt(76);
password += characters[character];
}
return password;
```

There is variables:

```
private final String[] characters = {
"A" , "B" , "C" , "D" , "E" , "F" , "G" , "H",
"I" , "J" , "K" , "L" , "M" , "N" , "O" , "P" , "Q" , "R" , "S" , "T" ,
"U" , "V" , "W" , "X" , "Y" , "Z", "a" , "b" , "c" , "d" , "e" , "f" , "g" , "h",
"i" , "j" , "k" , "l" , "m" , "n" , "o" , "p" , "q" , "r" , "s" , "t" ,"u" , "v" , "w" , "x" , "y" , "z", "0" , "1" , "2" , "3" , "4" , "5" , "6" ,
"7" , "8" , "9", "!" , "#" , "'" , "+" , "%" , "(" , ")" , "&" ,
"=" , "?" , "*" , "-" , "$" , "{" , "}" };
private String password = "";
```

Comment: can you show what generate() method contain?

Comment: It seems that you generate() function generating the same string on every click, correct your generate() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling generate() the first time `password.length() < 16` will always be false.
Put `String password` inside generate():

```
private String generate () {
String password = "";
Random random = new Random();
int character;
while (password.length() < 16) {
character = random.nextInt(76);
password += characters[character];
}
return password;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you generate() function generating the same string on every click, correct your generate() function.

Modify generate() function like this for create random password and pass argument length which you want for password.

```
fun generate(length: Int) : String {
        val allowedChars = ('A'..'Z') + ('a'..'z') + ('0'..'9')
        return (1..length)
            .map { allowedChars.random() }
            .joinToString("")
    }
```

Comment: I think there isn't a problem on function. On java same function create different passwords.

Comment: Actually, you have declared a password variable globally and it remembers password which generates first time, When you click again it return same password again because your condition become false.

Comment: So you can just declare the password as a local variable @phornbet answer